# Is there any accompaniment software for a USB midi keyboard?

Tags: software, rhythm, styles, accompaniment

Is there any accompaniment software for a USB midi keyboard, like Yamaha's Style function or Casio's rhythm function?

Basically I have a M-Audio Key Ring 49 and I would like the functionality of Yamaha's Style function or Casio's Rhythm function. I don't care much about the software cost.

Answer (score 3):

You want to google "auto accompainment software".

People seem to dig this: http://www.digibandapp.com/

Also: http://www.1manband.nl/

If you want something more advanced and beyond what your Ketron does, you may want to try out Ableton Live and the like:

https://www.ableton.com/en/trial/

As the name suggest, it is a live performance-oriented DAW that with a bit of programming offers you finer control over what you trigger, loops, chords and the like, and comes with a library of loops and styles.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about software costs, then check out Ableton Live.  Its a fully featured DAW that will allow you to jam along with loops and also record and arrange your results.